# How to return all facts that are less than or equal to an input value in prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate, comparison-operators

I'm new to Prolog and am struggling with this problem. I have a list of authors, books, and prices:

```
wrote(applying_uml,pauline_wilcox).
wrote(applying_uml,pooley_rob).
wrote(artificial_intelligence,boden_margaret).
wrote(artificial_vision,cantoni_virginio).
wrote(artificial_vision,levialdi_stefano).
wrote(bioinformatics,critchlow_terence).
price(applying_uml,72).
price(artificial_intelligence,92).
price(artificial_vision,48).
price(bioinformatics,57).
```

I am trying to write a predicate that given an input price, will return all the authors books and prices up to the input price. So far I have this:

```
specs(BK1, Aut1, P1) :- price(BK1, P1), wrote(BK1, Aut1).
```

Where P1 is the price being input, and BK1 and AUT1 output the books with that price and their author. But I can't figure out how to make it also return the books that cost less than that input price and their authors as well. For example if I input 57 as P1, it should return both artificial visions, and bioinformatics like this:

```
48 pounds
BK1 = artificial_vision,
Aut1 = cantoni_virginio ;
48 pounds
BK1 = artificial_vision,
Aut1 = levialdi_stefano ;
57 pounds
BK1 = bioinformatics,
Aut1 = critchlow_terence.
```

I've tried messing around with a second price variable P2 and making it <= P1, then checking price(BK1, P2), but it keeps failing. I'm wondering if maybe I need to use recursion but I can't think how to implement it. I have no no idea where to go from here, hoping someone can help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
find_book_under(PMax,BK1, Aut1, P1) :-
   specs(BK1, Aut1, P1),
   PMax >= P1.
```

It's not clear in your question why this didn't work out for you. This clause works provided that you query it with a specific value of PMax. Also, the comparison has to be done second, because the variables have to be instantiated for it to succeed.